# numberOfRowsInSection called for a section not being reloaded

Tags: ios, swift

In my tableview, when section == 0, I insert a row of help text for the user if all sections have zero items.

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if myArray.flatMap({ $0 }).count == 0 && section == 0 {
            return 1 //so we can show empty row helper text
        } else {
            return myArray[section].count
        }
    }
```

When allowing the user to delete rows manually, this works fine except for the situation when there are no rows in section 0 and I'm deleting the only remaining row elsewhere (say section 1).  In this case, the help text is not showing.

On delete, I call reloadSections for section 1.

```swift
myTableView.reloadSections([indexPath.section], with: .fade)
```

I've also tried a deleteRow and get the same behaviour.

```swift
myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

With either of the above, I get a crash:

> 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of
> rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be
> equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the
> update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from
> that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of
> rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I get the error message - section 0 wasn't touched by the delete and now has a row (which it didn't before the delete).  But how is that happening / why is numberOfRowsInSection even being called in this situation (when I'm intentionally not reloading section 0)?

If I just to a full myTableView.reloadData() - it works fine with no crash - but of course I lose the animation of the delete of the row the user is removing.

Ideas?

**EDIT: Solved with thanks to PaulW**

The issue is that numberOfRowsInSection can be called at any time for all sections for layout reasons.  As such, if I'm updating section 1 to delete the final item, then section 0 will return 1 on a reload.  So by proactively reloading section 0 in this case, I avoid the crash.

Inside my delete row function, I now do the following:

```swift
if tempRideArray.flatMap({ $0 }).count == 0 {          
     myTableView.reloadSections([0,indexPath.section], with: .fade)
        } else {
     myTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

Comment: `numberOfRows` can be called at any time for any section.  The tableview needs to know how many rows are in other sections so that it can adjust the scroll view offsets as required.  Your problem is that the row count for section 0 is changing unexpectedly due to its reliance on the content of `myArray`.  When you update the array you need to reload section 0 as well.

Comment: It's been a bit since I worked with something like this so bear w/ me.  Is the item you're deleting (from section 1) the only item in your array? Because of the way the message says section 0 gained a row, it makes me think that you deleted the one and only item from the array (so `myArray.flatMap({ $0 }).count == 0`), triggering `numberOfRowsInSection` to return 1 for section 0. If this is the case, I wonder if adding a call to `insertRows(at:with:)` or `reloadSections(_:with:)` would help indicate that new row to the system. You might want to look into `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()`.

Comment: @Paulw11 - thanks, that did the trick.  If you want to drop in an answer to that effect, I'm happy to accept it.  I solved it by checking if the array has zero items after a delete, but before the reload.  If so, I reload section 0 and the section with the delete.  If not, just the row being deleted.  Works perfectly.

Comment: @SteveB if you solved the issue would you mind share the your final result for community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numberOfRows(in section:)` can be called at any time for any section.

The tableview needs to know how many rows are in other sections so that it can adjust the scroll view offsets as required.

Your problem is that the row count for section 0 is changing unexpectedly due to its reliance on the content of `myArray`.

When you update the array you need to reload section 0 as well if the array count has changed from zero to non-zero or non-zero to zero.